# Clion не видит установленные заголовочные файлы c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, библиотеки, include, clion

Работаю в clion с компилятором от visual c++

Появилась необходимость использовать не предустановленные заголовочные файлы

Установил uwebsockets через vcpkg, в visual studio все отлично, а clion не видит:[image: В Clion]

Выдает ошибку:

```
C:\Users\USER\CLionProjects\SkillChatExample\main.cpp(6): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: uwebsockets/App.h: No such file or directory,
```

Comment: Нужно добавить параметр для cmake, читайте документацию.